# Arduino 3.3V Conversion

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, voltage-level, digital-analog-conversion

I am fairly new to Arduino. As far I know all official Arduinos run on 5 volts. Or there is Arduino versions that run from 3.3V? I need use Arduino with devices which chipsets all use 3.3V logic level. Do I need modify Arduino to make it  3.3V powered, like described in this [Tips](https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/3-3v-conversion), or there is another way? I plan get Arduino UNO R3 ATmega328P board (comes with bootloader for Arduino UNO ZT).

Comment: The best solutions to this are to move away from an antiquated ATmega to a modern MCU which achieves full performance on 3.3v.

Comment: Nucleo boards (ARM). And on Olimexino 32u4 it's even possible to switch between 3.3V and 5V. So many possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino Pro Mini comes in 3.3v and 5v versions.

Comment: Arduino Pro Mini is minimalistic, semi-finished board that comes without pin headers, no on-board USB, and no built-in USB circuitry, so it requires additional components and FTDI TTL Level Serial Converter Cable that should be connected, so the whole construction isn't very handy.

Comment: @minto. Soldering things is a basic ability here. FTDI is no-brainer; you need only one. The big plus: minimal footprint. Lately, I don't even solder pins; just solder the wires directly to the board for less hassle and to reduce overall height and fit the Pro Mini in tight spaces.

Comment: Soldering is not an issue, but I just preffer standalone device, with all required interfaces already built-in. As it not need to be pocket-size device, the minimal footprint just not required. Additionally, attaching external FTDI basic breakout board isn't convenient.

Comment: @minto. Last, but not least, Pro Mini is breadboard friendly. You can put a Pro Mini, an OLED display (1.8") and several led and push buttons on a small breadboard: a whole project in the footprint of an Arduino Uno. The FTDI also comes handy with things like SMS 800 modules.

Comment: I correct myself. I was thinking about a 0.98" OLED display

Answer (score 0):

You can use different possibilities:

1. Use Arduinos which are already 3.3V by default (like Pro Mini, Due if I recall right)
2. (removed after valid comment of minto below)
3. Use 5->3.3V adapters, most general devices have adapters which can be bought separately (for under 1$) to convert 5 to 3.3V (including logic level converters)

Comment: I think the point 2) `"Use the 3.3V pin on e.g. the Arduino Uno"` is simply wrong: the Arduino Uno has a 3.3V power source, but the digital I/O pins are based on 5V, not 3.3V. We can't to make the I/O pins 3.3V, unless we are powering the Atmega at 3.3V also.

Comment: True, I will remove it from the answer (was mixed up with powering in general)

Answer (score -1):

What about just getting the bare chip so you can run it at whatever rail you want? Seems like the simplest and easiest solution.